# Xcode - Created an iOS framework but can't use it in a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I've created an iOS framework with this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios#comments

When I add it to a completely new project, I can import my public header and I can build it successfully. The problem comes when I try to create an instance of an object from the framework; when building it, fails with 40 errors:

All errors are displayed like this:

*Apple Mach-O Linker Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVPlayerItem* < this is an example.

At the bottom it shows this message > *Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64*

At first I thought the problem was that the framework I created wasn't supporting arm64. I executed the following line in Terminal to check which architectures were supported by my framework:

*xcrun lipo -info MyFramework*

The output is > *Architectures in the fat file: MyFramework are: armv7 i385 x86_64 arm64*

I'm using Xcode 6.4.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Here are some images of the error list:

[image: first]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide complete error list.

Comment: @JohnTracid I've added the error list. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have some frameworks in your project like AudioToolbox or AVFoundation and also C++ library. Could you show what frameworks you added to project?

Comment: @JohnTracid Now that you told me, I added this: Foundation, AudioToolbox, CoreAudio, MediaPlayer, AVFoundation and libiconv.dylib. I still have 19 errors. What I noticed is that I have a class in my framework with the .mm (for obj c ++) extension. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Check my answer. You need C++ standard library if you use C++ in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I think that in your MyFramework project you used several iOS frameworks like AVFoundation and also C++ standard library (libstdc++.6.dylib). In your fat library you don't have them. You need to add this dependencies manually to that project.

Another good tutorial about creating iOS Framework is [iOS Framework Tutorial](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks. (I'll accept the answer when solved).

Comment: It works now. What I did was renaming AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm in the project using my custom framework. (and also adding frameworks needed). I'll upvote your answer for getting me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Phases in your Xcode settings. Select Target Dependencies. Add your framework Target (with Tests target). And Clean the project and delete your all derivedData and Run project. Very Easy.